# Sublime Text Editor snippet to remove parentheses

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext-snippet

Sublime is able to add parentheses, brackets (curly and square), apostrophes, and quotes to highlighted text by default.  I've tried but can't seem to find a way to have it remove those as well.  What I'd like to be able to do is highlight some text that is surrounded by parentheses and have it remove those.  Is there a good way to do that using snippets?

I suspect it can be done with use of allFollowingCharacter and allPrecedingCharacter but it seems those might be from a previous version of Sublime when those were in XML instead of the current JSON...?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [surround](https://github.com/jcartledge/sublime-surround) you can do this. Install it via Package Control. ([Package Control Installation](https://packagecontrol.io/installation))

Open the command palette:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Linux and Windows,

<kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Mac.

Search for `Surround: delete surround` and type in `(` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you are done!

[image]

Comment: Looks great.  I'll look into this, and then see about setting up shortcut keys for it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised this question isn't searched more regularly!

[BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter) is an excellent utility that includes convenient deleting of parenthesis. To cut to the chase, install BracketHighlighter and set `bh_remove_brackets` to whatever shortcut you'd like to be able to delete parentheses. Search up `bh_remove_brackets` in the [example sublime keymap](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/blob/master/Example.sublime-keymap) to see an example!